# Swift: Beacon ranging returns empty array when on phone call

Tags: ios, swift, location, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

We have an app that does beacon ranging using CLLocationManager - Core Location under Swift 4.  The ranging functions typically works fine, returning any beacons in range.  However, if a Bluetooth headset is connected to the phone, and a phone call is either received or made, the beacon ranging function is still called, but returns an empty array.  This happens with our app in the foreground.

Tried a beacon scanner (Beacon Scan) app from Apple store.  It also stops detecting beacons when on a phone call.

We're expecting beacon ranging to continue returning detected beacons while on a Bluetooth headset phone call.  Any ideas as to why it doesn't?  The exit region event also gets triggered.  When the phone call ends, the beacon ranging starts working again.  This is not a problem on Android.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the response from Apple.  Apparently beacon detection cannot be done while on a phone call with a Bluetooth headset.**

Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS).We have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations.

If you would like for Apple to consider adding support for such features in the future, please submit an enhancement request via Feedback Assistant (https://feedbackassistant.apple.com). For more information on Feedback Assistant, please visit https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/.

While a Technical Support Incident (TSI) was initially debited from your Apple Developer Program account for this request, we have assigned a replacement incident back to your account.

Best Regards,

Developer Technical Support
Worldwide Developer Relations
Apple, Inc.

> PLATFORM AND VERSION
>   iOS
>   We've tested with iPhones 6s (OS 12.3.1), 6s Plus (12.4), and 10r (12.4) using AirPods, Jabra and Plantronics headsets so far. All have this issue.
>
> DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM
>   We have an app that does beacon ranging using CLLocationManager - Core Location under Swift 4. The ranging functions works fine, returning any beacons in range. However, if a Bluetooth headset is connected to the phone, and a phone call is either received or made, the beacon ranging function is still called, but returns an empty array. This happens with our app in the foreground.
>
> Tried a beacon scanner (Beacon Scan) app from Apple store. It also stops detecting beacons when on a phone call.
>
> We're expecting beacon ranging to continue returning detected beacons while on a Bluetooth headset phone call. Any ideas as to why it doesn't? The exit region event also gets triggered. When the phone call ends, the beacon ranging starts working again.
>
> STEPS TO REPRODUCE
>   Implement a beacon detection solution using Core Location.  Or, install a beacon scanner app.  Connect phone to a Bluetooth headset.  While ranging beacons with a beacon on, make or receive a phone call via the Bluetooth headset.  Beacon detection fails while on the call.  As soon as the call is over, beacon ranging once again returns the filled array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the iOS bluetooth stack that prevents Bluetooth LE scanning from getting results while a phone call is active over a bluetooth connection.  It is certainly conceivable that this radio activity prevents other functions by the same bluetooth chip from working.  <strike>I have not witnessed this behavior myself.</strike>

You might want to characterize this further by dong some testing with:

- Various iPhone models
- Various headsets
- Various iOS versions

You may find the problem is specific to certain combinations of the above.  This will let you know the scope of the problem even if there is nothing you can do to prevent it, or even detect that the problem exists at any given time.

**EDIT: I can confirm this behavior.**

I tested this with an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.2.1, running the Beacon Locate app, while the phone was connected via Bluetooth to a Bose SoundLink II and a phone call was active.  See screenshot below which shows beacon detections stopping during the call (the image shows the distance going to -1), but then the detections dropped entirely.  As soon as I dropped the call, the detections resumed.

I will also note that if I simply play music (e.g. Pandora) over the same bluetooth connection, the beacon detections do not drop out.

It is possible that this is not a radio interference issue at all (as you note, the same issue does not exist on Android devices) but something imposed by iOS that blocks BLE scans during phone calls over bluetooth for some unknown (or unintended) purpose.

[image]

Comment: We've tested with iPhones 6s (OS 12.3.1), 6s Plus (12.4), and 10r (12.4) using AirPods, Jabra and Plantronics headsets so far.  All have this issue.

You mentioned you have not seen this behavior.  Can you tell me what set up you have used that does not have this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show the test conditions where I could not reproduce this behavior.

Comment: **CORRECTION** to my above comment: I have been able to reproduce this behavior.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Nice to know it's not just us seeing this.  Any thoughts on a solution?  Submit a support request to Apple, maybe?  Thanks.

Comment: You can try contacting Apple, yes, but don't get your hopes up.  Even if they do take action on it, you would not see any results until the next iOS release.